# Explanation of the concavity of conduction band and valence band of semiconductors at $k=0$

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, metals

For semiconductors, the conduction band is often drawn with a positive concavity at $k=0$ while the valence band below it is drawn with a negative concavity at $k=0$. Why is this figure never flipped in a semiconductor (or can it)? I have not seen the flipped picture is ever drawn. It is really universally true that the flipped picture never arise in a semiconductor and requires some explanation? Also for metals, is it universally true that the topmost band, the conduction band, always have positive concavity at $k=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Band structures do all sorts of weird things. Just look at Si if you want a conduction band that has the "wrong" concavity.

That said, the concavity you describe is common. By definition, it's true for direct-band-gap semiconductors with extrema at k=0, which are what you generally see drawn. In may cases, band gaps can be thought of as arising from level repulsion due to nearby energy levels (kind of like an avoided crossing, if you're familiar with those). If the bands are being repelled from eachother, you would expect them to bend away from eachother --- hence the concavity you observed. You can see this view of bandstructure arise in both the k.p and nearly free-electron models for band structure. For reference on the latter, see Ashcroft and Mermin chapter 9. In particular, see figure 9.4 --- especially sub figure (f), which shows how level repulsion can cause band gaps to occur at k=0.

Answer (score 1):

It is not always the case. For example, check Fig.1 for Silicon in [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.14.556). At $\Gamma$-point both conduction and valence bands are concave up.

Also, don't forget that the definition of conduction and valence bands depends on the Fermi level. So, potentially you can tune the Fermi level such that any two subsequent bands become conduction and valence bands. The only requirement is that all states in the band below the Fermi level are filled up and the band above the Fermi level is empty (for a semiconductor/insulator) or partially filled (for a metal). Bands can also touch, and in case the Fermi level goes through the touching point, it's a semimetal.

Comment: And don't forget things like semi-metals!

Comment: Exactly! Thanks for the comment. I edited the answer.

Comment: Don't forget that some semi-metals have the conduction band minimum lower than the valance band maximum, but offset in k-space (for example ScAs - https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.62.13538).